# Python Requests Reading text

Tags: python

I am trying to learn text processing. And using nltk.
Trying to follow the NLTK book.
When I try to read a text, it is reading it a little different.

```
import requests
url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554-0.txt"
response = requests.get(url)
response.text[:25]
```

[image]

How can I read the text without the highlighted part in the image uploaded.

Comment: Try slicing differently? `[1:25]`?

Comment: Your name.... lmao..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `unicode` format that you're seeing here.

What you should do is, convert the unicode string to `ascii` with `ignore` if not `ascii`.

Example:

```
a=u'\uffefHello World'
print(a.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
"Hello World"
```

Comment: import requests
url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554-0.txt"
response = requests.get(url)
raw = response.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
print(raw[:25]). prints b'The Project Gutenberg EBo'. what is that b in the beginning?

Comment: that's for `bytes`. Hope this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to `print` it and not put it just in the shell:

```
print(response.text[:25])
```

Should print:

```
The Project Gutenberg E8
```

The shell does `repr` on the value to find out what it should print

```
print(repr(response.text[25]))
```

will again print:

```
'\ufeffThe Project Gutenberg E8'
```